# DNS: Script to detect referrer and send to a directory

Tags: dns, ftp, webserver

I recently joined a site called DNSDynamic and was wondering if there was a way to make the URL that they supply redirect to a specific directory on my server since I am hosting multiple sites on multiple directories, but it simply asks for the server IP address and sends visitors to the root.

I figured I'd have to write a bit of code myself for this, what would you recommend?

I was thinking a bit of PHP in the root of the server that detects the referrer and redirects them accordingly using a meta code, am I right?

How would I go about this? Thanks. :)

Comment: This might be more on topic for [webmasters.SE](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @IlmariKaronen It's not as active over there as it is here, so I thought I'd give it a try on StackOverflow first. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With IIS you can certainly redirect to a subfolder based on the URL used using URL rewrite, I believe that there is similar functionality available in Apache.

URL Rewrite example:

```
    <rule name="RuleName" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="sitedomainname.co.uk$" ignoreCase="true" negate="false" />
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.sitedomainname.co.uk$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="sitedomainSubfolder/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
```